# Clustering geospatial and "ordinary" data

Tags: clustering, spatial

I have big dataset (~100k) of numerical parameters and their locations (lat, lng).
What approach should I choose to cluster such data?
Usual distance functions won't work in such case and calculating distance matrix would kill any hardware I have.

Regards
Paweł

Comment: Generally how to do clustering depends on what the clustering is used for and what features a "cluster" in your specific application is supposed to have. Here an important question is what role the locations are supposed to play. Should the clusters be optimally similar in location in the same way as in the numerical parameters? Or do you really only want to cluster the numerical parameters, but somehow accounting for spatial autocorrelation?

Comment: Regarding the computational issues, $k$-means should work for this dataset size (however this may not be a good method for what you want to do here), and another approach is to cluster a smaller subsample and then to assign the remaining observations one by one to the clusters.

Comment: I want to cluster numerical parameters with account for spatial autocorrelation

Comment: How do you want the spatial autocorrelation to be taken into account? Should your clusters be spatially connected? Something like this? https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8518643